# How do I print addition details on C++?

Tags: c++

For example, If i am printing a sum of numbers to the screen, but also need to print the addition details.

example:

```
cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " to " << x << " is: " << sum ;
```

this only displays the sum but i need it to display as `10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20`.

How do i get it to print the addition details?

I have already tried using different formulas to find the sum and the sum formulas work. All I need to know is how to print the addition details to the screen.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int x, y, sum;
    sum = 0;


    cout << "Input two integers: ";
    cin >> x >> y;

    for (int i = y ; i <= x; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }

    for ( int i = x; i == y; i++)
    {
        sum = i;
    }

    if ( x > y)
    {
        cout << "Sum of the values from " << y << " to " << x << " is: " << sum ;
    }
    else if ( y > x)
    {
        cout << "Sum of the values from " << x << " to " << y << " is: " << sum;

    }
    else if ( x == y)
    {
        cout << "Sum of the values from " << x << " to " << y << " is: " << sum;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code.

Comment: You have to do this yourself using `std::cout`

Comment: Can you print the number 10?  How about the character `'+'`?  How about the number 11?  How about another +?  Then could you print 12?

Comment: Depending on how you take in input you probably have to put the list of numbers in a vector and output that before you print the sum.

Comment: I daresay this is best done with a counter in a simple loop. Fold expressions are sexy, but come on! OP is a beginner, and this is not a task that requires big or even medium-sized guns. `for(int i = y; i <= x; ++i) { /* you figure out the rest */ }` is fine.

Comment: @drescherjm I added my code.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont im not allowed to do it that way. I have to figure out how to have the addition details print.

Comment: Instead of three separate loops, why don't you swap `x` and `y` if `x > y`? This way, `x` will always be the smaller one.

Comment: @FeiXiang my teacher made us do it this way so that it works if the user enters the smaller one first either way.

Comment: That's exactly what my method does, but more simply. Your code works, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @FeiXiang how do i change it to use your method?

Comment: Use an if statement to check if `x > y`, and if so, swap `x` and `y`. You know how to swap two numbers right?

Comment: @FeiXiang didn't i already do that in my code above?

Comment: You just need a for loop and a cout to print the details. You know x and y.

Comment: ***didn't i already do that in my code above?*** No you did not swap x and y in the code posted. Not swapping leads to duplicated code.

Comment: I meant potentially swapping the actual values of the variables (not where they're used) before you do anything else, right after you read the input. Something like `if (x > y) { int temp = x; x = y; y = temp; }`